# simple proof for $ \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \hat{x})=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing

Critique for proof is always encouriged I suppose, I'm notthe best expert on proving things in math usually... I wonder if more rigorous or clever technique/style could be used in this problem.

**task**

if there's set of numbers $\{x_1, x_2, ... x_n\}$
they have a mean of $\hat{x}$

prove that $   \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \hat{x})=0$

**answer**

Because original form of sum is always a finite sum it can be written in the form as follows
$(x_1 - \hat{x}) + (x_2 - \hat{x}) + (x_3 - \hat{x}) +... + (x_n - \hat{x})  $

separate into two sums and add them together
 $\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i )   +  \sum_{i=1}^{n} (\hat{-x} ) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \hat{x})  $

we know from the common arithmetic mean formula such that
$\hat{x} =   \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i /n)  \leftrightarrow  \hat{x} *n  =   \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i )  $

then we can write
$\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \hat{x})=   \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i )   +  \sum_{i=1}^{n} (\hat{-x} ) $
$= \hat{x}*n + \sum_{i=1}^{n} (\hat{-x}) $

on the right hand side sum we have just constant value being summed repeatedly, which means repeated addition is multiplication
$= \hat{x}*n - \hat{x}*n =0  $

Comment: You have the right idea.  Summation is commutative and associative $\sum (a_i+b_i) = \sum a_i + \sum b_i.$  By definition $\hat x = \frac {1}{n}\sum_\limits{i=1}^n x_i.$ And, $\hat x$ is a constant so $\sum_\limits{i=1}^n \hat x = n\hat x$

Answer (score 1):

You do have the idea. Depending on how much detail you want or need to include, you could make your proof more concise. For example, write:
$\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \hat{x})=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i - \sum_{i=1}^{n}\hat{x}=n\cdot \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i}{n}-n \cdot \hat{x} = n \cdot \hat{x} - n \cdot \hat{x} = 0$. It looks like you essentially explained each step.

Since you asked about rigor, one thing to note is that here, we used properties of the summation here (For example $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(a_i+b_i)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i+\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i$). Technically, you [define summations formally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Formal_definition) and use that definition to prove its properties (for summations, you use induction). Then for proofs like this, you use the results without proof of its properties.